# Python, Pandas: Keep only the newest and unique data inside dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Good evening,

the objects inside my dataframe can pop up as many times they want, always with additional - changing - extra data and at least with a unique timestamp (column with date is not unique), something like this...

```
id    |    object    |    additional_data    |    date          |    timestamp
1     |    item_a    |    ...                |    2014-04-15    |    10:16:22
2     |    item_a    |    ...                |    2014-04-10    |    18:19:01
3     |    item_a    |    ...                |    2014-04-10    |    17:59:43
4     |    item_b    |    ...                |    2014-04-13    |    10:16:22
5     |    item_c    |    ...                |    2014-04-15    |    00:01:59
6     |    item_c    |    ...                |    2014-04-14    |    08:46:00
7     |    item_d    |    ...                |    2014-04-15    |    10:12:47
```

Is it possible to filter the dataframe only for the unqique **and** newest data? For example like this:

```
id    |    object    |    additional_data    |    date          |    timestamp
1     |    item_a    |    ...                |    2014-04-15    |    10:16:22
4     |    item_b    |    ...                |    2014-04-13    |    10:16:22
5     |    item_c    |    ...                |    2014-04-15    |    00:01:59
7     |    item_d    |    ...                |    2014-04-15    |    10:12:47
```

Thanks for all your help and have a great day!

Comment: does this do what you want? `df.sort_values(by=['date','timestamp'],ascending=(0,0)).groupby('object').first()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly sort your dataframe by 'date' and 'timestamp' column by using `sort_values()`:

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['date','timestamp'],ascending=[False,False]])
```

Now use `drop_duplicates()` method:

```
df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['object'],ignore_index=True)
```

**OR**

you can also do this by `sort_values()` and `groupby()`:

```
df.sort_values(by=['date','timestamp'],ascending=[False,False]).groupby('object',as_index=False).first()
```